# Find the max value between two column and update accordingly in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `license` and another one is `device` in both the table I have one common column is `merchant_id`. 
In `device` table I have multiple records for a single merchant (means merchant_id is duplicate). 
But in `license` table `merchant_id` is unique (means no duplicate merchant_id). 
Now my requirement is I have to count number of rows from `device` table and need to update the counted number into `number_of_devices` column which is present in `license` table and already there are data in `number_of_devices` column so while updating in to `license` table I need to check the `MAX` value. If the count value is coming max then I need to update.

My tried queries:

```
update license l set number_of_devices = 
from (select count(*),merchant_id from device d group by merchant_id) 
d where l.merchant_id= d.merchant_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In a Derived table subquery, determine the `devices_count` per `merchant_id` from the `device` table.
- Join this derived table to the `license` table on `merchant_id`.
- Now, use [`Greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) function to get the maximum value out of the `devices_count` and the existing `number_of_devices` value, and `Set` it.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE license l 
SET l.number_of_devices = GREATEST(t1.devices_count, l.number_of_devices)
FROM (
      select d.merchant_id, 
             count(d.merchant_id) as devices_count 
      from device d 
      group by d.merchant_id
     ) as t1 
WHERE t1.merchant_id = l.merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the CASE command within your inner query to achieve that.
(doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html).
Example (untested):

```
update licence l set l.number_of_devices = (CASE WHEN (select count(*) from device d where d.merchant_id = l.merchant_id) > l.number_of_devices THEN (select count(*) from device d where d.merchant_id = l.merchant_id) ELSE l.number_of_devices END );
```

Hope that helps

Cheers

Nikao